# Reject or loop over user input if two conditions not met

Tags: python, loops, input

I am a real beginner with Python, although I am loving every minute of it so far.

I am making a little program that takes user input and then does stuff with it. My issue is that the numbers the user inputs have to

(1) All add up to not more than one (i.e. a1+ a2+ a3 \leq 1)

(2) Each individually be < 1.

Here is my code thus far (just the essential middle bit):

```
 num_array = list()


  a1  = raw_input('Enter percentage a (in decimal form): ')
  a2 = raw_input('Enter percentage b (in decimal form): ')
  ...
  an = raw_input('Enter percentage n (in decimal form): ')


li = [a1, a2, ... , an]

for s in li:
   num_array.append(float(s))
```

And I would love to build in something to make it demand the user re-inputs things if their inputs either exceed the requirement that

a1+a2+a3 >1

or that a1>1, a2>1, a3>1 etc.

I have a feeling this would be really easy to implement, but with my limited knowledge I am stuck!

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: I see that you need to read an n first which is the number of percentages the user will input. After that you should repeat reading a percentage n times (use a for statement to achieve this). Now, you can add a validation that each percentage is lower than 1 as you read it, or at the end. Also at the end you would add all the values and validate that their sum is not greater than 1. Put a repeat forever over all this code and only exit when you like, so if any validation fails, you start over.

Comment: You can start at https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: Thanks, @gplayer and @WalR! Those are really helpful suggestions, and thanks for making me think about the answer, not just giving me one :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input_list = []
input_number = 1
while True:

    input_list.append(raw_input('Enter percentage {} (in decimal form):'.format(input_number))

    if float(input_list[-1]) > 1:     # Last input is larger than one, remove last input and print reason
        input_list.remove(input_list[-1])
        print('The input is larger than one.')
        continue

    total = sum([float(s) for s in input_list])
    if total > 1:    # Total larger than one, remove last input and print reason
        input_list.remove(input_list[-1])
        print('The sum of the percentages is larger than one.')
        continue

    if total == 1:    # if the sum equals one: exit the loop
        break

    input_number += 1
```

Comment: Oh, my! This does just what I wanted and is easy to understand. Thanks for a great answer :-)

Comment: what you also could do to improve it is to set a certain `error` margin (like 10^-3) to catch floating point errors. So then it would be `if (1-error) < total < (1+error):`. If you pick 10^-3, the total may differ 0.1% from 1, at 10^-5, it may differ 0.001% from 1.

Comment: That's really fancy! Thanks!